# The generated token with vdomah JWT plugin in october cms is not accepted by the route with flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication, jwt, octobercms

Hello i'm using flutter and i built an api with october cms.
I used the plugin by vdomah for the JWT Authentication, i think i followed the README.md but when i try to send the token to the api, i think is not accepted, the code:

the route:

```
Route::post('storephoto', function (Work $Work, Request $request) {
    ...
    $Work->save();
})->middleware('Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken');
```

the flutter side:

```
upload(String fileName) {
    http.post(AppUrl.baseURL + "/storephoto",
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
        },
        body: {
      "name": workNameController.text,
      "images": fileName,
      "description": descriptionController.text
    }).then((result) {
      setStatus(result.statusCode == 200 ? result.body : errMessage);
      if(result.statusCode == 200) {
        Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => MainScreen()));
      };
    }).catchError((error) {
      setStatus(error);
    });
}
```

I printed the token in this function, and it exists, but i can't see the error in console.

I tried to make a GET route and the api seems to work in the browser, the message:

```
{
    "error": "token_not_provided"
}
```

Now i think the token generated is not signed, or not recognized, how i can do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Once I faced the same issue, not sure there is some issue in the plugin, and doing the below change solved it.

> plugins/vdomah/jwtauth/Plugin.php in this file do below change.

[image]

if you have any doubts please comment.

and can you use middleware like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' =>         
    ['\Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken']], function() {
    Route::post('storephoto', function (Request $request) {           
        //..code
    });
});
```

> as if I do like this its working

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, it does not work maybe I understand, I am wrong the last part of the readme.md, can you explain me exactly where i have to put the methods getAuthApiSignupAttributes?

Comment: I think it's only needed if you need your custom data its optional, can you add middleware like in code may be it should work as for me its working